Cloud Build inline yaml - escape character in variable name
My Spring app requires a variable named spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name to be set.
For other variables I have been able to use '--set-env-vars' and replace periods with underscores and all caps (e.g. for my.variable '--set-env-vars' _MY_VARIABLE=foo) but for hyphenated variable names this is failing.
How do I escape the hyphen in the variable name? (I'm doing this within the "Edit inline configuration" part)
I've tried DATABASE\-NAME but this didn't work

As stated in Binding From Environment Variables
To convert a property name in the canonical-form to an environment variable name you can follow these rules:

Replace dots (.) with underscores (_).

Remove any dashes (-).

Convert to uppercase.


For example, the configuration property spring.main.log-startup-info would be an environment variable named SPRING_MAIN_LOGSTARTUPINFO.
Also have a look at this link

Thank you, removing the dashes worked. It appears some backslashes got inadvertently added into the variable name in your answer. I have made an edit which is pending acceptance
